# Creating an object class with elements of varying but set length

Tags: java, arrays, char

I want to create an object (Wine) that contains a set of data where each data element is a different size (year, region, maker, variety, etc.). I want to be able to print these out in a tabular format using the set length of each element. I've searched and tried lots of ways but can't find the answer.

my class definition looks like this:

```
public class Wine {
char[] year;
char[] area; // Wine area
char[] brand; // Wine brand
char type; // R or W or F
char[] variety;
char bin;
int numbottles;
```

I can read data in from a txt file but the elements are shortened to the text content plus a space so the tabulation is lost.

I've tried this in my main section without success:

```
wine.year = rightpad(tokens[0].toCharArray(), 5) ;
wine.area = rightpad(tokens[1].toCharArray(), 9);
            ....

static char[] rightpad(char[] text, int leng) {
    for(int i = text.length - 1; i < leng; i++){
        text = (new String(text) + ' ').toCharArray();
    }
    return text;
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Chris A

Comment: Why not just you a `String` rather then `char` arrays?

Comment: What is your expected and actual output?

Comment: I've used the String.format method without success. I'm importing the list line by line, splitting it and adding each elelment to the Wine object (first trying to format the relevant items with the desired length) then creating an object Array list wineinfo (ArrayList<Wine> wineInfo = null;). then using wineinfo.add to add each wine to the array. When I print out the array it only shows one space between each element.

Comment: @ChrisAppleby Show how you use it please. My answer tell you how to use it to add some padding... I can't guess how you used it to not get the correct output. Edit the question with the problem please...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is my parse routine which reads through the String line and pulls out each Object element then adds them to the Object at the end:

```
 static List<Wine> parseLine(String line, List<Wine> wineInfo) {
    String year = null;
    String area = null;
    String brand = null;
    String type = null;
    String variety = null;
    String bin = null;
    String numbottles = null;
    String drinkyear = null;
    String cost = null;
    Wine wine = new Wine(year, area, brand, type, variety, bin,
            numbottles, drinkyear, cost);
    int length = line.length();
    int j = 0;
    char yr[] = new char[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        yr[j] = line.charAt(i);
        year = new String(yr);
        j = j + 1;
    }
    char temp[] = new char[7];
    j = 0;
    for (int i = 3; i < 10; i++) {
        temp[j] = line.charAt(i);
        area = new String(temp);
        j = j + 1;
    }
    char temp1[] = new char[12];
    j = 0;
    for (int i = 10; i < 22; i++) {
        temp1[j] = line.charAt(i);
        brand = new String(temp1);
        j = j + 1;
    }
    char temp3[] = new char[2];
    j = 0;
    for (int i = 22; i < 24; i++) {
        temp3[j] = line.charAt(i);
        type = new String(temp3);
        j = j + 1;
    }
    char temp2[] = new char[21];
    j = 0;
    for (int i = 24; i < 45; i++) {
        temp2[j] = line.charAt(i);
        variety = new String(temp2);
        j = j + 1;
    }
    char tmp[] = new char[6];
    j = 0;
    for (int i = 45; i < 51; i++) {
        tmp[j] = line.charAt(i);
        bin = new String(tmp);
        j = j + 1;
    }
    char temp4[] = new char[3];
    j = 0;
    for (int i = 51; i < 54; i++) {
        temp4[j] = line.charAt(i);
        numbottles = new String(temp4);
        j = j + 1;
    }
    char temp5[] = new char[4];
    j = 0;
    for (int i = 54; i < 58; i++) {
        temp5[j] = line.charAt(i);
        drinkyear = new String(temp5);
        j = j + 1;
    }
    char temp6[] = new char[7];
    j = 0;
    for (int i = 58; i < length; i++) {
        temp6[j] = line.charAt(i);
        cost = new String(temp6);
        j = j + 1;
    }

    wine.setYear(year);
    wine.setArea(area);
    wine.setBrand(brand);
    wine.setType(type);
    wine.setVariety(variety);
    wine.setBin(bin);
    wine.setNumbottles(numbottles);
    wine.setDrinkYear(drinkyear);
    wine.setCost(cost);

    wineInfo.add(new Wine(year, area, brand, type, variety, bin,
            numbottles, drinkyear, cost));

    return wineInfo;
}
```

}

I then used a collections Comparator method to sort:

```
 List<Wine> wineByYear = new ArrayList<Wine>(wineInfo);
 Collections.sort(wineByYear, Wine.YearComparator);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

```
String.format("%-8s", "test") // "test    "
```

You set the length of the `String` and use a negative value to add the space to the right (without the minus, to the left)

Complete information about the format are available in [Formatter - Format String Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Comment: To see the full program go to http://www.cappleby.net.au/exportToHTML/Main.java.html

Comment: @ChrisAppleby Don't expect us to check your code... include a snippet in your question if you want...

Comment: In the end I created my own parser to step through each line to create the correct length of string for each element of the object. Thanks for your comments. Chris A

Comment: @ChrisAppleby you've never edited your question, so both answer proposed are correct. You should see [what to do when you have an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: My apologies. Final answer now included.

Answer (score 0):

Use   org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi)

```
StringUtils.leftPad("text", 7) // return "   text"
```

Comment: I tried that as well as creating my own rightpad function.

Comment: StringUtils it's save method's 
Look description please . 
It also gives you a lot more possibilities to use. Like  StringUtils.leftPad("bat", 8, "yz")  = "yzyzybat"